# How to Attach onkeypress Event to a Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, smarty

**Question Update**

How should I check the condition of the `if` statement using `onkeypress`? I am using [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal) and therefore need the `{literal}` tags.

```
{literal}
if(event.keyCode==13) {
  alert('hi');
}
{/literal}
```

Below is an example implementation.

```
<textarea onkeypress="{literal} if(event.keyCode==13) {alert('hi');} {/literal}" class="fc_tab_txt"></textarea>
```

Comment: It's {literal}, not {litral}

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, purely in javascript - without using jQuery, by creating your own function called `SayHi()` and putting it in the `<head>` section of your webpage. The function could have example implementation as follows:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  function isblank(field) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) 
    {
        alert('hi');
    }
  }
// -->
</script>
{/literal}
```

You can call this function using the `onkeypress` event as follows:

`<textarea onkeypress="SayHi()" class="fc_tab_txt"></textarea>`

Answer (score 1):

As Borgtex suggests, you should read up on the jQuery API. In general, this is how you attach event handlers using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your jquery">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#text_area_id").keypress(function() {
        alert("I found Hogwarts.");
    });
</script>
<!-- random HTML stuffs -->
<textarea id="#text_area_id"></textarea>
```